# Mule 4 Kafka connector with SASL-SSL-security-protocol (SCRAM-SHA-512)

Tags: apache-kafka, mule, mule4, mule-connector

I am trying to integrate Mule application with Kafka using SASL-SSL-Security-protocol (SCRAM-SHA-512). Below knowledge article from Mulesoft says (Only Kafka connector version 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.0.9 and 3.0.10 support SASL_SSL security protocol with GSSAPI mechanism.
The current Kafka connector version 4.0.0 doesn't support SASL_SSL as there is a known issue SE-15680.). Here is the link to that article

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-configure-Kafka-connector-to-use-SASL-SSL-security-protocol-with-Kerberos-GSSAPI-mechanism

Is that the issue still exists (Latest Kafka connector I am seeing from Mulesoft release note is 4.4.0). https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/kafka-connector-release-notes-mule-4

If someone clarify that would be really great. I tried looking for the fix(SE-15680) in the release notes and could not get one. We do have lot of applications planned to develop Mule integrating with Kafka with SASL-SSL-security-protocol (SCRAM-SHA-512)

Comment: I do noticed that they released it in this version (https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/kafka-connector-release-notes-mule-4#new-features-4) . Knowledge Article needs some updated information (https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-configure-Kafka-connector-to-use-SASL-SSL-security-protocol-with-Kerberos-GSSAPI-mechanism)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SASL/GSSAPI support was added in the Kafka connector version 4.2.0. It is recommended to use the last release though.